# Rails Losing Params during Post Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where I don't know how many text_fields there are going to be.  For each row in the table/form, there is the basename of the file, and a hidden field next to it so it is passed in, along with the 2 text fields, the `params[:lots[key][lot_number][:low_range][:high_range]`.

Once I get to the Controller I only have 2 - 3 of the original 8 sets of fields that where produced.  I'm not sure why these other fields are being left behind.

I tried doing it with 15+ fields and it still only gets 5-7 of the lots each time.

The information I get is correct and formated correctly. I'm just always missing over half of the lots that are rendered in the `@video_filenames` loop

View:

```
<%= form_tag  mass_create_from_media_admin_event_lots_path(@event), :method => :post do %>
            <table class='list'>
                <th>Lots</th>
                <th>Sub Lot Creation</th>

                <% if !params[:videos] || params[:videos] == '1' %>
                    <% @video_filenames.reject(&:blank?).uniq.each do |filename| %>

                        <% basename = File.basename(filename, '.*') %>
                        <% unique_key = Time.now.to_f %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= basename %><%= hidden_field_tag "lots[#{unique_key}][lot_number]", basename %></td>
                            <td><%= text_field_tag "lots[#{unique_key}][low_range]" %> <%= text_field_tag "lots[#{unique_key}][high_range]" %></td>
                        </tr> 
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </table>
            <%= submit_tag "Create Lots" %>
        <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def mass_create_from_media  
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    lots = params[:lots]
    abort(params.to_s)
    errors = []

    lots.each do |key , lot|
        if @event.lots.where(:number => lot[:lot_number]).empty?
            new_lot = @event.lots.new(:number => lot[:lot_number], :start_at => Time.now, :end_at => Time.now + 1.hour)

            if !new_lot.save
                errors << new_lot.errors.full_messages
            else
                if lot[:low_range].present? && lot[:high_range].present?
                    index = lot[:low_range]
                    while lot[:high_range].to_i >= index.to_i
                        sub_lot = @event.lots.new(:number => lot[:lot_number] + '-' + index.to_s, :start_at => Time.now, :end_at => Time.now + 1.hour)
                        index = index.to_i + 1
                        sub_lot.save
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end

    if errors.present?
        flash[:error] = "Errors creating lots: #{errors.join(', ')}"
    else
        flash[:success] = "Lots successfully created"
    end

    redirect_to mass_new_admin_event_lots_path(@event)
end
```

HTML Output:

```
<input id="lots_1369421745.947125_lot_number" name="lots[1369421745.947125][lot_number]" type="hidden" value="101z">

<input id="lots_1369421745.947125_lot_number" name="lots[1369421745.947125][lot_number]" type="hidden" value="115z">

<input id="lots_1369421745.947125_lot_number" name="lots[1369421745.947125][lot_number]" type="hidden" value="161z">

<input id="lots_1369421745.948125_lot_number" name="lots[1369421745.948125][lot_number]" type="hidden" value="20z">

<input id="lots_1369421745.948125_lot_number" name="lots[1369421745.948125][lot_number]" type="hidden" value="20z">

<input id="lots_1369421745.948125_lot_number" name="lots[1369421745.948125][lot_number]" type="hidden" value="47z">

<input id="lots_1369421745.948125_lot_number" name="lots[1369421745.948125][lot_number]" type="hidden" value="87z">

<input id="lots_1369421745.948125_lot_number" name="lots[1369421745.948125][lot_number]" type="hidden" value="rock_on">
```

Text Inputs:

```
<input id="lots_1369421745.948125_high_range" name="lots[1369421745.948125][high_range]" type="text">

<input id="lots_1369421745.948125_low_range" name="lots[1369421745.948125][low_range]" type="text">
```

Comment: Can you paste the server log output.

Comment: I posted it for you.  Its when the post is called and right after completion

Comment: Using Chrome web inspector or Firebug, make sure your 8 text and hidden fields have the correct name. e.g. `<input name="lots[key][lotnumber]" type="text">`.

Comment: I found the problem is that the Key is not unique because its processing to fast that its getting the same Time stamp.  Any ideas on a different way to get a unique key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<% @video_filenames.reject(&:blank?).uniq.each_with_index do |filename, index| %>

                        <% basename = File.basename(filename, '.*') %>

                        <tr>
                            <td><%= basename %><%= hidden_field_tag "lots[#{index}][lot_number]", basename %></td>
                            <td><%= text_field_tag "lots[#{index}][low_range]" %> <%= text_field_tag "lots[#{index}][high_range]" %></td>
                        </tr> 
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I often have that problem of making things harder than they need to be.  I need to remember to take advantage of indexes.  Thank you, I now changed my code to this :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `<% unique_key = Time.now.to_f %>` is not generating uniq keys. As you can see in the html, keys `1369421745.947125` and `1369421745.948125` are repeated.

So, you have to change your "algorithm" to generate uniq keys.

Answer (score 0):

I changed  `<% unique_key = Time.now.to_f %>`  to `<% unique_key = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 %>`